# how to create link in asp.net website in order to link me to mvc project?

Tags: asp.net

I have two websites. one in ASP.NET and the other in the MVC4 . I would like to create a link in ASP.net project, so when I click on this Link it will lead me to MVC website. do you any idea how I can do it please ?? Personally, I think it will be through create Link in ASp .net but how ?

Kind Regards,

Ish

Answer (score 0):

If this projects are spearate websites (i assume this from your question) the only choice is to hard-code link into ASP.NET. Of course you can put in configuration to easy change it on production server.

Comment: it is actually separated . But how I can hard-code link into asp.net please ?

Comment: Thanks Garath :) But I would like to pass parameter in this <a href="http://your_server/your_site">link</a>  ??

Comment: In query string like this: `<a href="http://your_server/your_site?param1=something">link</a>`